# 3D Arrays not working

Tags: java, string, methods, multidimensional-array

```
public static String[] getWords(int cat, int diff) {
    String topic[][][] = new String[3][3][3];
    switch(cat){
        case 0:
            topic[0][0][0] = "Paris";
            topic[0][0][1] = "London";
            topic[0][0][2] = "Sydney";
            diff = 0;
            topic[0][1][0] = "Toronto";
            topic[0][1][1] = "Florida";
            topic[0][1][2] = "Frankfurt";
            diff = 1;
            topic[0][2][0] = "Barcelona";
            topic[0][2][1] = "Vancouver";
            topic[0][2][2] = "Zimbabwe";
            diff = 2;
        case 1:
            topic[1][0][0] = "Halo";  
            topic[1][0][1] = "Fifa";                   
            topic[1][0][2] = "GTA";
            diff = 0;                  
            topic[1][1][0] = "Skyrim";
            topic[1][1][1] = "HITMAN";
            topic[1][1][2] = "Batman";
            diff =1;
            topic[1][2][0] = "Minecraft";
            topic[1][2][1] = "Zombieville";
            topic[1][2][2] = "BoderLands";
            diff =2;
        case 2:
            topic[2][0][0] = "Acura";
            topic[2][0][1] = "Audi";
            topic[2][0][2] = "Bmw";
            diff = 0;
            topic[2][1][0] = "Bentley";
            topic[2][1][1] = "Buggati";
            topic[2][1][2] = "Honda";
            diff = 1;
            topic[2][2][0] = "Lamborghini";
            topic[2][2][1] = "Rolls-Royce";
            topic[2][2][2] = "Mercedes";
            diff = 2;
    }
    return topic[cat][diff];
}
```

So this my method with the 3d arrays and i want to know if i did it right, and also if i call it in the main method will it work?? I used switch statement since someone recommended me it, i'm really new to java, as u can see
This is for the game Hangman

Comment: Did you notice that you haven't got a `break` statement at the end of each case? That's very unlikely to be desired. We can't really tell whether or not it *works* as we don't know what it's trying to achieve - but it's unlikely to be the best way of doing it, IMO.

Comment: in the main method it will be asked what category and difficulty level they want to play and whatever they choose it will read into the method and go to that section, how do you do that

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't. Your switch does not contain any `break;` statements, therefore after it meets the first `case` which evaluates to true, it will then perform all statements after that until the end of the switch, or until you `break;` or `return` something.

Additionally, the calls to:

```
diff = 0;
// ...
diff = 1;
// ...
diff = 2;
```

Are redundant, as the assigned value is never used.

So it should be:

```
switch(cat)
{
    case 0:
        topic[0][0][0] = "Paris";
        topic[0][0][1] = "London";
        topic[0][0][2] = "Sydney";

        topic[0][1][0] = "Toronto";
        topic[0][1][1] = "Florida";
        topic[0][1][2] = "Frankfurt";

        topic[0][2][0] = "Barcelona";
        topic[0][2][1] = "Vancouver";
        topic[0][2][2] = "Zimbabwe";
        break;
    case 1:
        topic[1][0][0] = "Halo";
        topic[1][0][1] = "Fifa";
        topic[1][0][2] = "GTA";

        topic[1][1][0] = "Skyrim";
        topic[1][1][1] = "HITMAN";
        topic[1][1][2] = "Batman";

        topic[1][2][0] = "Minecraft";
        topic[1][2][1] = "Zombieville";
        topic[1][2][2] = "BoderLands";
        break;
    case 2:
        topic[2][0][0] = "Acura";
        topic[2][0][1] = "Audi";
        topic[2][0][2] = "Bmw";

        topic[2][1][0] = "Bentley";
        topic[2][1][1] = "Buggati";
        topic[2][1][2] = "Honda";

        topic[2][2][0] = "Lamborghini";
        topic[2][2][1] = "Rolls-Royce";
        topic[2][2][2] = "Mercedes";
        break;
}
```

Comment: than how would you call it in the main method like if the user says the category they want to play is cars, and the difficult is easy how would u do that? if it will be like this

Comment: @N00b_JAVA Do you only ask what difficulty they want once, and every time? Because if so, it should be outside the switch. Or are you saying that each block is a different difficulty?

Comment: just me 50 cents,
don't use "static" construction in method, you can move this array into static field.

Comment: under case 0, the words paris,london,Sydney are easy for the category places and than words tornto, florida, frankfurt are medium for the category places. Under case 1 the category is games and its the same thing like place, and it's going to ask the user if they want easy, medium, or hard and on which category places, games or cars. Than the program should go to this method and get the word from the difficulty given and category given

Comment: @N00b_JAVA Personally, I wouldn't do it like this, I'd build `MenuGroup` objects which hold items and their difficulties inside `Menu` objects which hold games inside `Categories` which the user selects.

Comment: yea but, i only want to use arrays and i think 3d arrays will be perfect, only thing is that i don't know how to use them or how to call them in

Comment: do you know how i can call it in the main method

Comment: I'm not sure you even need a break, nothing is overwritten. I think these strings should be setup as static and **getWords** then just consists of *return topic[cat][diff];*

Answer (score 1):

you need a break; in between cases. It'll just simply go through every case since there's no breaks. Well every case if it's case 1, and 2&3 if it's 2, and just 3.

So 3 is the only one that'd break properly, because since it's the last you don't need one.!